# Recursor and induction functions in dependent type theory

Tags: induction, recursion, type-theory, homotopy-type-theory

I'm reading HoTT book and I'm not sure if I really understand how the recursor function is related to the induction function. It is stated that product types are said to be :

> a degenerate example of a general framework for inductive types

Thus, I think the recursor function for product types is a particular case of the induction function for product types : $$rec_{A \times B} : \prod_{C : \mathcal{U}}(A \rightarrow B \rightarrow C) \rightarrow A \times B \rightarrow C$$
$$ind_{A \times B} : \prod_{C : A \times B \rightarrow \mathcal{U}} \left( \prod_{(x: A)} \prod_{(y : B)} C((x,y)) \right) \rightarrow \prod_{x : A \times B} C(x)$$
Am I right by considering the recursor function as the induction function with C not being dependent of A and B ?

Also, this is my first post on this website, please tell me whether I have to rephrase something in a particular way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you're correct. The recursor is like the induction principle, but with a less informative type. (Or, the induction principle is recursion with a more informative type.)

Comment: I'm not sure what it means for one type to be "less informative" than another.  Both of them give complete information about the behavior of an element of that type; as far as I can see the types are just different.

Comment: That makes sense in this particular example, but there are plenty of functions with type $Π_{R:U} R → (R → R) → ℕ → R$ that don't have a sensible refinement to $Π_{R: ℕ → U} R\ 0 → (Π_{n:ℕ} R\ n → R (\mathsf{suc}\ n)) → Π_{n:ℕ} R\ n$. Also, does it still make sense in this scenario if we can use some classical/non-parametric trick to gain information about $A$ and $B$?

Comment: Exactly my point: the types are just different, it's not that one is "more informative" than the other.  What exactly are you claiming that it gives "more information" about?  No inhabitant of one type is also an inhabitant of the other type.  Is it that there's a natural forgetful map from one to the other?

Comment: The recursor can be obtained from induction by using a constant family. Induction can be obtrained from the recursor by producing $Σ_{p:A×B}C(p)$ _together with_ the fact that the actual behavior of the recursor will produce a value in the right fiber. The induction principle says _in the type_ that it produces a value in that fiber. These mediations aren't literally $λ(x:T). x$ in a completely annotated surface syntax, and in such a scenario a term simply can't have two distinct types, of course.

Comment: From  a more semantic (or, descriptive, vs. intrinsic) perspective, they might literally be the same thing, with a different description imposed on it. They might have the same semantic value/realizer/unannotated presentation, where one type explicitly tells you how it acts if you imagine slicing up  your $C$ output into a family. Or, if you like, 'the same' universal arrow occurs both as $A×B → C$ and as $id → f$ in the slice category, but the latter more obviously tells  you about an equation, despite the fact that you can figure out that equation from the first description.

Comment: Oh, I see you are thinking of typing a la Curry.  (I wouldn't call that unadorned "semantic", though -- the kind of semantics I'm familiar with is a la Church.)

Comment: Oh sure, you could have Church style semantics, too. I think both ways of thinking about things can be useful/complementary. It occurs to me that with HoTT, it might be dubious whether you can really get away with imagining that $Π_{R:U} ...$ is 'just' an unrefined $Π_{R: T → U} ...$ anymore. 'Type erasure' has to be a more subtle issue at the _least_. But I guess that's a topic for some other time, because stack exchange is complaining that we're making too many comments. :)

Comment: Yes, it's much harder to make sense of Curry-style semantics for HoTT.